# Create Google App Function by using Big Query information

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

The current issue is to create a single source for the product price.

This is a link for what I'm looking for [SAMPLE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```

Actual steps:

Connect to big query and pull table which contains ( ProductID, ProductName, ProductPrice)

Create a function:
What I have used with Google sheets

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, DATA!A:C, 3, 0), 
                              VLOOKUP(A1:A, DATA!B:C, 2, 0))))
```

And now looking for

```
function CHECK_CURRENT_PRICE(INPUT) {

  Pull ProductID, ProductName, ProductPrice WHERE ProductID = INPUT

  return ProductPrice;
}
```

So then I can go to Google Sheets and do like this

```
=CHECK_CURRENT_PRICE(8867)

And it will return 6.45
```

**P.S.** I will update this question when will get some more information regarding how to make this happens

**ALTERNATIVE:**

Create a function which will read product price from sheet "DATA" based on ProductID

E.G.

```
function CHECK(input) {
  Look where ProductID = input
  Get Product Price
  return ProductPrice;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
function CHECK(INPUT) {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('LINK TO GOOGLE SHEET');
  query.setQuery('SELECT C WHERE A = 2016');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}



function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  // Called when the query response is returned.
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  return data

}
```

ERROR - **ReferenceError: "google" is not defined.**

Comment: See the documentation on the [BigQuery service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery)

Comment: @Altigraph Have updated the question, look for alternative section, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `=query` function?

Comment: @TheMaster Have amended question, have a look - UPDATE 2

Comment: @TheMaster ANy ideas?

Comment: He was referring to the [`=QUERY` function built into Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), not a GAS function. "google" is not a class in Google Apps Script; you are probably looking at the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#Query), which is not Apps Script. You can see an example of how it compares with Apps Script and how the query API can be invoked from Apps Script [here](https://www.consulity.com/content/GASSAppVsGViz.aspx) -- but what you're trying to do is much better handled with the native `=QUERY`

Comment: I meant the query formula inside Google sheets. `=query()`

Comment: @TheMaster Formula is good, but I need to build the function, any ideas at all?

Comment: Why? It seems you're going to use it as a custom formula any way.

Comment: @TheMaster The idea of the formula is that it will connect to a single point of truth of product price table and when someone will create new google sheet, they can just add this script and use up-to-date product prices

Answer (score 1):

```
function CHECK()
{
    var url = "SHEET LINK";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var json = response.getContentText("UTF-8");
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    var price = data;

    return price
}
```